# How to deserialise SQLAlchemy JSON to Decimal using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have got my code working to serialise an object which has `Decimal` and store in JSON in my PostgreSQL utilising [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438052/using-a-custom-json-encoder-for-sqlalchemys-postgresql-jsonb-implementation) , i am using Flask-SQLAlchemy so have created my own custom `apply_driver_hacks` method to pass in a `json_serializer` which will serialise `Decimal` objects - so all good so far.

However on pulling the data back out , the deserializer loads these values as float. I've searched high and low but can't seem to find any way to reload as Decimal - i can pass in a custom `json_deserializer` as an option to Flask-SQLAlchemy but cant find a way to pass in any value such as `use_decimal=True` which is what I would use if using `simplejson` to load up Json with `Decimal` .

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: @IljaEverilä -  Thank you very much! - that does indeed work and solves my problem which just a couple of lines of code, really appreciated for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a callable that passes [`parse_float=decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to `json.loads()` as `json_deserializer`. A simple function such as

```
def json_deserializer(*args, **kwgs):
    return json.loads(*args, parse_float=decimal.Decimal, **kwgs)
```

should do.